# In PowerBI report how to retain selection through the pages or make the report scrollable

Tags: powerbi

I have a hierarchy slicer and depending on the selection, I have a lot of graphs to display. Like the voltage, motor speed etc for each item in the hierarchy.

I am not able to fit all the graphs on one page of the report and was not able to make the report scrollable so that I can add more graphs. So I created more pages to display the graphs. But of course the hierarchy selection is not retained through the pages and the user does not want to choose the hierarchy for every page.

So does anybody know how to either make the report scrollable so that I can fit more graphs in it or retain the selection on the next page for the same datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this on the power bi pages

"You can change the 'canvas' workspace by deselecting any tiles, then in the Visualization side toolbar, click on 'Paint Roller' then expand the Page Size drop down arrow. There you can choose some default workspace pixel sizes or set your own, choose Type: Custom. I have mine set to 1300 x 2000 (h) pixels working on a Surface Pro3. It gives me a nice long page to work with."

Answer (score 0):

The dashboards online are to be used for scrolling through multiple graphs. Consider putting one graph on each page of a dashboard, then pin the active page to the dashboard in the sequence which you would like. Each graph can then be placed where you want in the dashboard, which is able to be scrolled like you want.

To **retain the selection** on each page of a report, you need to add a report-level filter. The report level filter remains active for all pages in the report. The report level selection(s) you save on the desktop version will be saved when published in the report.

If a user wants to update the report level filters on the web report, all they have to do is open the filters on the top right of the report and then they can select what they want.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, but the Report level filter doesn't work, because my selection is through a hierarchy slicer, and if I replace that with a report level filter, then I cannot get the hierarchy(if I add the levels of hierarchy to the report filter, then only the values of the lowest level are displayed and not the parent).......Regarding the dashboard idea, the report would be scrollable, but each graph would still need its own heirarcy selection which I want to avoid

Comment: So, if you're not using a date, but instead are using categories, would it not help to simply put each of those categories as report level filters? Then the person looking at the reports can select the combination of categories he/she wants to see across the report. I know it's not as pretty, or convenient, but until they provide report level slicers, I think this is the only solution.

Comment: Hmm thank you for the suggestion, but report level filters will not work for the hierarchy, because the user would hve to remember which child belongs to which parent, which is not easy...So maybe they just hve to reselect from the heirarchy in every page. Too bad powerbi doesn't allow the report to be scrollable and expand as we add more graphs!